# JQuery - Selecting nested elements by class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select `li` elements by class names but it's not working as I want. See the following code:

```
var HTML = '<div class="product">' +
    '<ul class="listing">' +
    '<li class="item">1</li>' +
    '<li class="item">2</li>' +
    '<li class="item">3</li>' +
    '<li class="item">4</li>' +
    '<li class="item">5</li>' +
    '</ul>' +
    '</div>';


alert($(HTML).find('.product .listing .item').html()); //does not work
alert($(HTML).find('.listing .item').html()); //WORKS!
```

Why I am not able to select items product class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `.product` is one of the selected elements, it's a **top level** element. `.find` would try to find the elements with class `product` **inside** the `.product` element.

Maybe you are looking for [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

```
alert($(HTML).filter('.product').find('.listing .item').html());
```

Comment: Works perfect. I tried the same code but instead of `filter` I used `find`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) looks for descendents of the current jQuery selection. In this case, `$(HTML)` is already the `div` with the `product` class, so `.find('.product .listing .item')` would look for descendents of the top `div` with the class of `product`. In this case, using `.find('.listing .item')` is correct.

Comment: FWIW, `.find()` looks for all descendants, not just children.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for catching that misdirection!

Comment: Thanks, but there is another div `product1` which has similar items. If I use this code `.find('.listing .item')` it's going to select products from `product1` div as well.

Comment: @jason: If it's in the same HTML string, see the other answer for how to use `.filter`. Otherwise, it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if this is something you're looking for?

```
var HTML = '<div class="product">' +
    '<ul class="listing">' +
    '<li class="item">1</li>' +
    '<li class="item">2</li>' +
    '<li class="item">3</li>' +
    '<li class="item">4</li>' +
    '<li class="item">5</li>' +
    '</ul>' +
    '</div>';


alert($('.item', HTML));
```

please see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/s1s3zjdL/

Comment: How is that different from `$(HTML).find('.listing .item')`, besides omitting `.listing`? It also doesn't really answer the question.